# Which logical operator do I want to use in this mysql statement?

Tags: mysql, boolean-logic

Which is a better way to select ans and quest from the table?

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE option='ans' OR option='quest'";
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE option='ans' AND option='quest'";
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Whoops, so sorry. Please see edited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your second statement is not going to return any results.  A record cannot have option=ans and option=quest at the same time.

Comment: I think you can remove the word "Probably" from your statement :)

Answer (score 4):

It's not a question of a 'better' way - only the first one works. Even though you want option=ans *and* option=quest in your results set, the WHERE clause is executed once per row. So you're telling MySQL "give me a row where option=quest and option=ans" i.e. option is two values at once, which is impossible. You actually want to get rows where either is true, which is why you use `OR`.

I think this reads better:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE option IN('ans','quest');
```

Answer (score 2):

If the rows that represent question have `option` set to `'quest'` and rows with answer have `option` set to `'ans'` then you should use `option='ans' OR option='quest'";`. Also a row cannot represent both question and answer so using `AND` will not select any rows.

Answer (score 1):

This select will return all rows whos options is `ans` or `quest`

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE option='ans' OR option='quest'";
```

This select on the other hand will not return any rows since a column has only one of those values

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE option='ans' AND option='quest'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you want your search to return both answers and questions:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE option='ans' OR option='quest';
```

It can also be written:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE option in ('ans','quest');
```